# Securely use Firebase JS SDK with React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-security

Currently I'm building an app using React Native, Expo and Firebase I was wondering from anyone who has worked with the Firebase JS SDK and React Native via Expo what approach they took to securely communicate with and initialize Firebase.

For development I'm using environment variables to store API keys and other information about my Firebase project and I'm doing everything such as user auth, firestore actions like get and create docs etc. client side. But i know that everything client side isn't considered secure and id like to be releasing the app / pushing it to production soon and I'm worried about security issues because there will be sensitive keys used for things like stripe. All in all i wanted to get an idea for how to do it with firebase so i can adapt to other sensitive items. I've used Django in the past and have read that using an api server is much more secure but I've also heard using serverless solutions like AWS lambda is also a good approach. Curious as to what approach others have taken when faced with this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public? My answer there explains how to secure the server with security rules and app check.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just read it thanks for the link! i did not find it when i searched for an answer lol